# Save a selection of text to an RTF document without opening a new doc and switching windows

Tags: microsoft-word, rtf

Is there a way to save a selected block of text to an RTF document without opening a new document, pasting the content in the new document, saving the new document, and then returning to the original doc? That's a lot of hoops to jump through when all I want to do is highlight a block of text, right click, and select "Save As".

I tried creating a macro to do the same, but there's a lot of screen switching going on and I can't find a way to reliably return to my original document, eg. if I have multiple documents open, I often get returned to a random document vs. the document I started with.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `windows(FILENAME).Activate` function to pop between windows?  It is an effective way to do it.   Here is an example, however I am assuming this may not be what you are looking for:

```
Windows(FileName).Activate
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Paste2_LE_SUMHere"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
```

I am having RTF woes as well.  I have a macro that requires I open an RTF, select all of the contents of the document and paste it to a .docx file.  I have no trouble accessing the .docx file, however am never able to switch to the RTF file.  I consistently get an error : Run-time error 5491 - The requested member of the collection does not exist.   I get this error regardless of whether I am using relative or absolute pathing, or just try to access the filename directly.   Any thoughts?